# PHP login issue - mysql_num_rows is not valid

Tags: php, mysql, function, logging

good day every one
well i have a login problem, everytime i try to log i get this message

1. Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
   resource in /home/a6720525/public_html/functions/sandbox.php on line
   25
2. Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
   result resource in /home/a6720525/public_html/functions/sandbox.php
   on line 27

the login form

```
 <form class="admin_login" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">

    <input class="username" name="username" type="text" id="username" size"40" placeholder="Adress email"/>

    <input class="userpass" name="password" type="password" id="password" size"40" placeholder="Mot de pass"/>

    <input class="addbutton" type="submit" name="button" value="connexion"/>
    <input class="addbutton" type="submit" name="insc" value="Inscription"/>
    <input class="addbutton" type="submit" name="mpo" value="Mot de pass oublier?"/>
    </form>
```

the function i use

```
function members ($dbc, $qu) {

if(isset($_POST["username"])&& isset($_POST["password"])){
    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9\@\-\_\|\,\.\\p{L}\\\\]#i', '', $_POST["username"]);//filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);// filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the Mysql database
    $qu = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $re = mysql_query($dbc, $qu);
    //........make sure person exists in data base
    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($re);// count the row nums
    if($existCount == 1){//evaluate the count
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($re )){
        $id = $row["id"];
    }
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
    }else{
        echo 'That information is incorrect,try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try `function members (&$dbc, $q) {`

Comment: You need to switch your DB credentials from `$re = mysql_query($dbc, $qu);` to `$re = mysql_query($qu,$dbc);` and doing the same for your function `function members ($q,$dbc) {` - In `mysql_*` the connection comes second, not first as done in `mysqli_*` - Assuming that `$dbc` is your DB connection.

Comment: Can you try my suggestions without calling the function? @user3185201

Comment: same problem with doing that i've tryed that

Comment: Are you in fact connected to DB? @user3185201

Comment: You have several dangerous security flaws here: 1) mysql_ functions are deprecated and should be migrated to mysqli or PDO. 2) You are storing plaintext passwords. 3) You are stripping non alphanumerics from passwords, making them much easier to guess/crack

Comment: Plus, I'm guessing here. Does your DB connection file contain `mysqli_*` function? @user3185201 - notice the added `i`

Comment: And if not (`mysqli_*`), then check to see if your DB connection file/class contains something like `mysql_select_db($DB)` @user3185201

Comment: yes the data base is connected, and other function return data normaly

Comment: same problem with mysqli, sorry

Comment: yes the database connection contain i

Comment: that's the problem then, you can't mix `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions. @user3185201 - Change `$re = mysql_query($dbc, $qu);` to `$re = mysqli_query($dbc, $qu);` and `$existCount = mysql_num_rows($re);` to `$existCount = mysqli_num_rows($re);` and `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($re )){` to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($re )){` and it should work. Let me know.

Comment: @Fred -ii-, no nothing like mysql_select_db($DB)

Comment: no tryed that, not working

Comment: I hope you didn't try that with my first suggestions? @user3185201

Comment: And what is the `$q` for in `function members ($dbc, $q)`? @user3185201

Comment: no its a $qu, sorry my bad

Comment: Ok, well I don't know what else to say that could help you. You basically need to change all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and to troubleshoot from there. @user3185201

Comment: thank you very much freddi i never seen someone who tryed to help me like that, i know this is a serious problem, :)

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["username"])&& isset($_POST["password"])){
    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9\@\-\_\|\,\.\\p{L}\\\\]#i', '', $_POST["username"]);//filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]);// filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the Mysql database
        $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($r);
        if($userCount == 1 ) {
            while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {

            $id = $user['id'];
            $pass = $user['password'];  
            $us = $user['username'];

            }
                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                $_SESSION["manager"] = $us;
                $_SESSION["password"] = $pass;
                header("location:index.php?page=business");
                exit(); 

        }else { echo 'That information is incorrect,try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
                }


}
```